# The Netherlands or just Netherlands in parenthetical constructions

Tags: definite-article, proper-nouns

In sentences like

> The project will be monitored by the company's office in Amsterdam,
>   *the* Netherlands.

or

> The project will be monitored by the company's office in Amsterdam
>   (*the* Netherlands).

should **the** be used or not?

Comment: I don't believe we ever say "the Netherlands" without the "the" in any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it does take the article *the*.

> The project will be monitored by the company's office in Amsterdam, the Netherlands.

I found several sentences mentioning...

> *...in New York City, the United States.*

This included the sentence from the book **World Made Global: Stories of Africal Christianity in New York** by *Mark Gornik.*

> *...the most public of ways that Christianity from Africa had arrived in New York City, the United States and the West.*

You may further search for the exact phrase (use quotes) - "in new york city, the united states" on Google and find examples from authentic sources including newspapers.